# Which object should be saved in a Django object sequence?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I alter an object representing a user's dog as so in Django:

```
user.dog.species = "Golden Retriever"
```

To save this information, should I do this:

```
user.dog.save()
```

or this:

```
user.save()
```

Would both work since saving the user also implies saving child relationships? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? I'm not confident the second method recursively calls save to related objects.

Comment: I did, and the second method didn't work. I was just wondering if it sometimes did for certain cases and what the standard was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ORM does not save the whole object tree, so if you create a new `user` and a new `dog` you would need to save both.